# How to run dispatch on a saga function when a button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a use case where I might be dispatching actions(saga) later in the game. I have an application where user fills out a form and later on when user clicks on submit that time the saga action will be called through which i will get response from api. But i also have another worker saga that run in the initialization time of application. Somehow only initialize works other forks don't work -

sagas/applicationSaga.js

```
export function* initialize() {
  yield call(getAppInfo);
}

export function* getAppInfo() {
  try {
    const appInfo = (yield call(
      AppApi.getAppInfo
    )).data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}

export function* submitDecision({payload}) {
  try {
    const submitDecision = yield call(AppApi.submitDecision, payload)
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}

export function* applicationSaga() {
  yield fork(takeEvery, ActionTypes.INITIALIZATION_REQUESTED, initialize);
  yield fork(takeEvery, ActionTypes.SUBMIT_DECISION, submitDecision)
}
```

sagas/index.js

```
import { applicationSaga, initialize } from "./applicationSaga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([applicationSaga(), initialize()]);
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for your reducer, action and store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way to implement this -

```
export function* initialize() {
  yield take(ActionTypes.INITIALIZATION_REQUESTED);
  yield call(getAppInfo);
}

export function* submitDecision({payload}) {
  try {
    const submitDecision = yield call(AppApi.submitDecision, payload)
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
export function* applicationSaga() {
  yield all([
    initialize(),
    takeEvery(ActionTypes.SUBMIT_DECISION, submitDecision)
  ]);
}
```

sagas/index.js

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { applicationSaga } from "./applicationSaga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([applicationSaga()]);
}
```

Basically I had to yield all in root saga and in my actual application saga I can keep adding workers attaching to my watcher saga.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to invoke a generator function in Saga. Store, actions and reducers must be implemented properly in order to make the application be in sync with the data. Please have a look at [How do I call a Redux Saga action in a `onClick` event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905328/how-do-i-call-a-redux-saga-action-in-a-onclick-event) this.

**yourJS.js**

```
import store from "YOUR_LOCATION/store";

submit = () => {
  store.dispatch({type: "SUBMIT", payload: YOUR_PAYLOAD});
}

<button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
```

**SAGA.js**

```
import { takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";

export const watchSubmit = function* () {
    yield takeLatest("SUBMIT", workerSubmit);
};


function* workerSubmit(action) {
    try {
    // Your code
    } catch {
        message.error("Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i wanted. My problem is I wanted a single saga which had all my forks and then dispatching them whenever required which is not working